# How can I make initializing random non blocking pool faster?

Tags: random, buildroot

I have an issue with my Buildroot generated Linux and rootfs image for Zynq board. The problem is that random nonblocking pool is generated about 2 minutes after boot, just after I get kernel message like below:

`random: nonblocking pool is initialized`

It is annoying, because it blocks TCF Agent lanuch, and I have to wait to run anything remotely, or use scp during first 2 minutes.

I'm using Buildroot 2017.08. Is there anything I can do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entropy in VMs and iOT devices might often not be enough.

Install `haveged`.

From `man haveged`:

> NAME
>          `haveged` - Generate random numbers and feed Linux's random device.
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          `haveged`  generates  an unpredictable stream of random numbers harvested
>          from the indirect effects of hardware events on hidden processor  state
>          (caches,  branch  predictors, memory translation tables, etc) using the
>          HAVEGE (HArdware Volatile Entropy Gathering and  Expansion)  algorithm.
>          The  algorithm operates in user space, no special privilege is required
>          for file system access to the output stream.
>
> Linux  pools  randomness  for  distribution  by  the  `/dev/random` and
>          `/dev/urandom`  device interfaces. The standard mechanisms of filling the
>          `/dev/random` pool may not be sufficient to meet demand on  systems  with
>          high needs or limited user interaction. In those circumstances, `haveged`
>          may be run as a privileged daemon to fill the `/dev/random` pool whenever
>          the supply of random bits in `/dev/random` falls below the low water mark
>          of the device.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tried and it helps, but it sill gets quite some. The thing is, that I don't really need this good randomness, but I need nonblocking pool to be filled fast. In images generated with Petalinux (it is based on Yocto) message `random: nonblocking pool is initialized` appears just after first line of Init. If it's not possible to have poll fast initialized with software, is there any way to force it to be initialized, with "weak" randomness?

Comment: I would investigate a hw random generator or using the GPU, if any, to get random numbers.